# Find the basis for the kernel and the image, for a linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving

Let $T : \Bbb{R}^3 → \Bbb{R}^3$ given by $$T(x, y, z) = (x + 2y − z, y + z, x + y − 2z).$$

Using Gauss-array and reducing the system of equations to row echelon form I got:

$\{(3,-1,1)\}$ is a basis for the kernel and 
$\{(1,0,1),(2,1,-1)\}$ is a basis for the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matrix of $T$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & -2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the Gaussian elimination gives the reduced row echelon form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus a basis for the image is $\{(1,0,1),(2,1,1)\}$ (the first two columns of the matrix of $T$) and a basis for the kernel is obtained from the equations
\begin{cases}
x_1=3x_3\\
x_2=-x_3
\end{cases}
so we get $\{(3,-1,1)\}$